# How to loop an animation in BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am trying to make a walking animation for my character in BGE, but I can't figure out to duplicate or loop the animation. This is so I can than make the animation "loop end" when you hold down the up arrow to make the animation play.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/how-can-i-copy-all-selected-keyframes

Comment: Also see: [How may I create a continuously looping animation?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/440/290)

Answer (score 3):

***Update:***
*If this answer seems out of place, the original question was* "How do I Duplicate Keyframes?"

---

Probably the easiest way is to the [*Dope Sheet* editor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/DopeSheet). There are several ways to get there:

- Click the icon on the bottom left corner of the 3D view and select *Dope Sheet*

  [image]
- Click on the dropdown that says *Default* on the *Info bar*, and select *Animation*. (Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> twice)

  [image]

  This will take you to the [*Animation layout*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Screens#Screens), with a [*3D view*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View), [*Graph editor*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/Graph), and *Dope sheet*.

From the *Dope sheet* or the *Graph editor*, select keyframes, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate.

## Looping in the BGE:

Once you have an animation that ends where it starts, you can make it loop in the Game Engine with *Logic Bricks*:

1. Go to the *Game logic* editor (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>)
2. Add a *Keyboard Sensor* (*Add sensor > keyboard*) and set the key by pressing the button next to the word *Key*.
3. Add an *Action actuator* (*Add actuator > Action*) and set the *Action* value to your walk animation, set the *end* value to the last frame of your animation, and set the *Action playback type* to *Loop End*.
4. Connect the logic bricks by dragging the dot next to the *Sensor* to the dot next to the *Actuator*. An *And Controller* should be automatically created between them:

[image]