# How to duplicate keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

How do i duplicate keyframes into the same object? I need this for a cyclic animation. I press Shift+D and move the keyframes in the Dopesheet, but the animation doesn't continue after the original keyframes.

**Update** : It seems that I'm not able to animate any bone after frame 30. Is this a bug? I use Blender 2.78a

**Update** : This is my set up :

[image]

Comment: Did you accidentally set your action to an nla. The nla can have a limited length. Uploading your blend file will help others answer your question morte easily.

Comment: @Leander I'll upload it now, hold on

Comment: @Leander so, yeah, this is the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy/paste keyframes you use the highlighted buttons below:

[image]

To fix the other issue You need to unpin the animation in the NLA editor as shown below and the animation will be there after frame 30 normally

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To Copy/Paste keyframes in the same object you can easily go to the Dope Sheet right click to choose the action you want (Shift+Right click) to choose more then one action then you can simply (Ctrl+C) to copy the keyframe then go to the frame you want to paste it and (Ctrl+V).

Example:

These 3 frames make the name pop and to copy it i marked all the actions i needed by (A) to pick all or choosing by (Shift+Right click) each action and then simply (Ctrl+C) to copy it.

**!!!!!most important while copy/pate keep mouse on the dope sheet!!!!!!!**

Later choose the frame you want to paste it on, and then simply (Ctrl+V) and it will be pasted like that:

[image]