# Rigging:: is it possible to duplicate animation settings in Blender?

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

so i've created some feathered angel wings and im struggling to figure out how to mirror the wings and the armature that already hold animations(Prety much ive modeled,rigged and animated one wing, and was hoping that i could copy,past, flip and then combine armature and meshes for export). this is meant to be for a character within unity but so far im unable to get it working without blowing up a wing, or animating both the wings at the same time. animating them at the same time is a struggle to keep them symmetrical.

Was wondering if theres a way to combine to create one armature and mesh without having to tediously animate two sets of wings?

Side note, if anyones got a good way to do this with copy rotation that would be cool!

[image: 2x wing armatures]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1860/how-can-i-copy-all-selected-keyframes

Comment: ive duplicated the wing and flipped it, which all works fine and stuff but my problem is i wanto combine the duplicate to the original and keep the animation as one in a single mesh. the same goes for the bones, i wont to combine the bones to create one armature instead of two